# Colors in rendered image are too dark?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I was halfway through modeling a character when I decided to open a second viewport and see how it would look rendered. I really like how the texture and colors look when I have the model set as a solid, but when I try to render it, the colors are too dark and some objects seem faded, and a lot less solid. 
[image: This is what the rendered version looks like next to the solid version]

Is there any way that I can make the rendered image look more like the view I normally see? I am using Blender version 2.77. Does anybody know what I could try to fix this? I can post screenshots of my settings too if that helps, but I wasn't sure if the problem was my lighting or the materials, so here are both:

[image]

This is my first time modeling so I'm sorry if there is a really obvious solution! I would really appreciate some help. (also I can show more of my settings if needed)

Comment: Solved the color problem by enabling ambient occlusion, thanks for your reply tho Billy. I still need help with the flickering colors at the barrel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more lights.  Currently, you have one dim light.  Try creating a sun lamp, and putting it near your character.  This will make it a lot brighter.